# From the change set, it's not clear which repository has changes in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

From the change set, it's not clear which repository has changes in Jenkins,
I have this function:

```
@NonCPS
List<String> getFilesList() {
  def changedFiles = []

  for (changeLogSet in currentBuild.changeSets) {
    for (entry in changeLogSet.getItems()) {
        changedFiles.addAll(entry.affectedPaths)
    }
  }
  return changedFiles
}
```

it returns the changed files from two repositories , but i want to ingnore the one repository how can I do that ?